# Facebook Insights shows both Client and App Version as "unknown" for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-insights

I've integrated FB insight on my iOS app. According to FB documents:

> You can pinpoint events coming from a version under development (vs. one that's in production) by choosing the App Version dropdown as shown in the image above. This will filter the events shown to that version. (**The App Version for your app will be logged automatically from the version stored in the iOS app's bundle**.) You can similarly filter by Event Name.

Ref. URL  : [FB Insight integration](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/app-events#testing)

But for my app, both ***Client*** and ***App Version*** filed shows **Unknown** for all the Insight events. Do I need to perform any separate API Call for this?

Thank you,

Akhil

Comment: I have the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I reported this bug to Facebook Developers at http://developers.facebook.com/bugs and they fixed it, and will roll out a patch on 11/4/2014.

Although the method is deprecated, this code does work and will populate AppVersion with the latest Facebook SDK:

```
[FBSettings setAppVersion:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"v%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"]]];
```

I logged a bug with Facebook about this issue:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/issues/665

Good luck!